# bootstrap-4 album card display: more/less

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am adopting the card concept from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/ .  Alas, I don't want all my cards on the table.  How would a viewer not be overwhelmed by 100 cards?

Has someone put together javascript to show only the first x rows and allows the browser user to show more cards or fewer cards?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually not a Bootstrap question - but rather ux issue. I guess your answer is one of the following:

- pagination - display first 10, more on other pages
- some carousele, slider swiper or whatever they tend to be called - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/
- auto load on scroll

If you insist to display all and hide some you can use for instance this:

```
$('div.yourCardClass:lt(9)').show();
```

to show first 10 cards

Comment: it's both.  I will take the easiest solution possible.  pagination with JS on the same page would be ideal.  I will tinker with hide/show solutions next...

Comment: Good call - pagination is easy and commonly used, so your audience will be ok with that.

Comment: Anyway - if you're ok with my answer - accept it in the system. It's a green tick next to the header of my answer. Thanx.

Comment: would love to get a self-contained working example...

Comment: Example of what - pagination? It depends on what you're using to build your functionality. From bootstrap side all is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/